# QT Quick - TextField background and borde

Tags: qt, background, border, qml, input-field

I am starting with QT and  trying to style a TextField using the following QML code:

```
property Component textfieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    background: BorderImage {
        source: control.focus ? "images/input-border-focused.png" : "images/input-border.png"
        border.left: 0 ; border.right: 0 ; border.top: 0 ; border.bottom: 4
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a way of setting a border like this and also an icon inside the field just like in the image below?

[image] The blue part is the background of the window.

If so, how can it be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the question here, exactly?

Comment: The border is set wit ha background image. And the icon here is inside the component. The border image is just 8px width and it is repeated along the input. I wanna know if I can set a icon and a border background for this input.

Answer (score 2):

Well since you have to use a Component for the TextFieldStyle, you are not restricted to use BorderImage, you can create your own Field using for eg a Rectangle like this

```
TextField {
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        textColor: "black"
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            border.color: "red"
            border.width: 3

            Image {
                width: 10
                height: 10
                source: "qrc:///inner.png"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since Rectangle has border property you can use it directly to set border.

Comment: yes, but this will give me a input with all the borders, I'd like it with the bottom border only, and I didn't find anything like "border.bottom.witdh" is there anything like that?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately there's no such property for Rectangle element. But you can create a Custom component for it. Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534489/qml-control-border-width-and-color-on-any-one-side-of-rectangle-element).

Comment: Please, update your answer with the link mention, so I can mark it as the correct one. I solved this using the link you mentioned.

Comment: This is not available in Quick Controls 2.