# Hover over header of a tableView columns

Tags: hover, qml, highlight, mouseover

I have a simple `TableView` with 4 `TableViewColumns`, I'm not usually working with qml, so I'm not really sure how to work properly inside this code.

What I want is that I need a mouse-over the `TableView` headers (column names). I checked all over and did not found any of a certain simple solution to my problem.

I have tried to use a tool-tip inside the `TableVIewColumn` but it never shows up, and I have seen that Mouse Area is not supported inside the `TableViewColumn`. Maybe the solution is simple but I am not aware of it for
the moment.

```
Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    TableView {
        id: table
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        headerVisible: true

        TableViewColumn {
            id: time
            role: "t-stamp"
            title: "Time"
            width: 60
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            id: d
            role: "id"
            title: "SignId"
            width: 40
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            id: sid
            role: "s-id"
            title: "StratId"
            width: 50
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            id: stratname
            role: "strat_name"
            title: "StratName"
            width: 200
        }

        Connections{
            target: MessageTabelModel
            onUpdateView:{
                  table.resizeColumnsToContents()
            }
        }
        model: MessageTabelModel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableView` has a [`headerDelegate`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#headerDelegate-prop) property that contains mouse information:

> In the header delegate you have access to the following special
>   properties:
>
> - styleData.value - the value or text for this item
> - styleData.column -
>     the index of the column
> - styleData.pressed - true when the column is
>     being pressed
> - styleData.containsMouse - true when the column is under
>     the mouse
> - styleData.textAlignment - the horizontal text alignment of
>     the column (since QtQuickControls 1.1)

So you can use `styleData.containsMouse` for your needs, for example with a simple basic text:

```
headerDelegate: Text {
    color: styleData.containsMouse ? "red" : "black"
    text: styleData.value
    // ...
}
```

Or if you want more customization:

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
    height: 20
    implicitWidth: headerText.paintedWidth
    border.color: "black"
    // ...

    Text {
        id: headerText
        color: styleData.containsMouse ? "red" : "black"
        text: styleData.value
        anchors.fill: parent
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, this is actually helpfull, just a single question I have in addition. When I add the headerDelegate and use my hover, the lines between the columns dissapear, and I dont know why.

Comment: Because your header delegate becomes the text only, so the frame disappears. You can customize the delegate entirely by wrapping the text around a Rectangle to give borders for example (see the second example I added in my answer). You might also be interested by this answer to be able to customize borders separately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562823/4503757