# How to draw a single sided line border in QML

Tags: qml, border, shapes

I've got 3 basic elements in a rectangle and I'd like to draw line separations between them.
I don't find an easy way to achieve that, as a `border-left` would do in CSS.

```
Text {
    id : txtNote
    text : (__notes.length>0)?__notes[0].extname.name:"--"
    anchors.right: txtNoteAcc.left
    leftPadding: 5
    rightPadding: 0
}

Image {
    id : txtNoteAcc
    height : 20
    width : 20
    anchors.right: txtNoteHead.left
}

Image {
    id : txtNoteHead
    height : 20
    width : 20
    anchors.right: parent.right
}
```

Now laid out as:

[image]

And the goal is to have it a similar way (this example is a Java one):

[image]

I've found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534489/qml-control-border-width-and-color-on-any-one-side-of-rectangle-element), but I don't call it "simple" and it is 7 years old.

Rem: I'm working with QML 5.9 (so Shape is not available).

Comment: To draw a line, just use a `Rectangle` with a width of `1`. Does that work?

Comment: No. This draws a line all around. I'm looking for a line on the left and right sides only. Like in CSS ```border-width: 0px 1px;```

Comment: No it doesn't. Using `border.width` would put a border all the way around a Rectangle. But I suggested using `width`, not `border.width`. Just position the Rectangle on the left or right. I'm not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Use a rectangle as a border. It is working fine. Thanks.